# How to avoid loops in Polybar with Golang

Tags: go, sh

I'm creating a plugin that allows me to turn on and off the Philips Hue lights along with Polybar.

When I use the 'exec' property towards the Golang binary, it enters into a loop and the lights turn on and off.

How can I make it toggle on and off?

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

type config struct {
    ip   string
    user string
}

type State struct {
    On bool `json:"on"`
}
type StatusResponse struct {
    State State `json:"state"`
}

func main() {
    var cfg config

    flag.StringVar(&cfg.ip, "ip", "myip", "PHUE IP address")
    flag.StringVar(&cfg.user, "user", "my-user", "PHUE User")
    flag.Parse()

    response := getLightStatus(cfg.ip, cfg.user, "1")
    response2 := getLightStatus(cfg.ip, cfg.user, "4")

    if !response && !response2 {
        turnOffLight(cfg.ip, cfg.user, "1", "on")
        turnOffLight(cfg.ip, cfg.user, "4", "on")
        fmt.Println("encendido")
        return

    }

    if response && response2 {
        turnOffLight(cfg.ip, cfg.user, "1", "off")
        turnOffLight(cfg.ip, cfg.user, "4", "off")
        fmt.Println("apagado")
        return
    }

}

func turnOffLight(ip, user, lightID, action string) {

    url := fmt.Sprintf("http://%s/api/%s/lights/%s/state", ip, user, lightID)

    var turnStatus string

    if action == "on" {
        turnStatus = `{"on":true}`
    }
    if action == "off" {
        turnStatus = `{"on":false}`
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPut, url, strings.NewReader(turnStatus))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("hubo un error al hacer el update %s", err)
    }

    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    // Send request
    client := http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to send PUT request: %v", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // Check response status
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        log.Fatalf("Unexpected response status: %s", resp.Status)
    }

}

func getLightStatus(ip, user, lightID string) bool {
    url := fmt.Sprintf("http://%s/api/%s/lights/%s", ip, user, lightID)

    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("hubo un error 1 %s", err)
    }

    var status StatusResponse
    dec := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body)
    //dec.DisallowUnknownFields()

    err = dec.Decode(&status)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error al leer la respuesta 2:", err)
    }

    resp.Body.Close()

    return status.State.On
}
```

```
 [module/hue]
type = custom/script
 format="Philip HUE"
 format-prefix = %{T2}%{F#f6e58d} %{F-}%{T-}
 exec = echo " "
 click-left= exec ~/.config/scripts/main
```

I tried to pass the code to Bash, but I don't know what else to do to prevent it from entering a loop.

The issue with the approach I used (with left-click) is that I can't display status icons on polybar. What I'm ultimately aiming for is to show an on and off focus according to the status, which I can only achieve if I use exec.

Comment: Your Polybar configuration needs to ensure that the script is executed only when a specific action is performed (e.g., a left-click on the module). You've already started this with the click-left property.

Comment: The issue with the approach I used (with left-click) is that I can't display status icons on polybar. What I'm ultimately aiming for is to show an on and off focus according to the status, which I can only achieve if I use exec.